# WSo2 Governance Registry

Tags: rest, registry, wso2, wso2-governance-registry

I am evaluating WSO2 for our SOA governance solution. Few questions

1. It provides a way to document services. Is there a way to document each operations listed in WSDL or resources of a RESTful service? I am not able to find this information.
2. How do I provide information about RESTful services?
3. Is there a policy enforcement?

---

Thanks for all the responses. I did look at API manager. Looks good but have couple of questions

1. I couldn't find a way to document endpoints for various environments. only 2 URLs supported - for sandbox and for production. How can I provide url for more environments?
2. Is it possible to customize lifecycle?

Answer (score 0):

1. and 2. You can define your own metadata this means you can store any data (the new data types are defined via XMLs which you upload to the server), there is a tutorial by the wso2 team with an example on how to do that.
2. I'm afraid I don't get what you mean in 3. Do you want different users to be able to create different type of artifacts?

This is a tutorial I've found useful: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pXfxiZlOtH0

You can also find documentation on the wso2 website

Answer (score 0):

To me it sounds like you might want to have a look at Wso2 API Manager 1.0, in fact it provides a nice interface to write your documentation for APIs in the 'publisher' side.

Also you will have all the information the user needs to consume the Restful Service + an API key to Authenticate in the 'store' side of the API Manager.

You will not have to worry about G-Reg because the API manager already include one and allows you to easily govern your SOA services.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

In SOA deployment, you can use WSO2 ESB as the  PEP (Policy Enforcement Point).
Please follow [this](http://wso2.org/library/articles/2011/08/finegrained-authorization-restful-services-xacml) article for more details. In that kind of deployment you can use mounted WSO2 Governance Registry server as a policy store. That will facilitate you to maintain the service policies in central repository and governance capabilities like Versioning, Life cycle management, Notifications...etc.